# Static HTML pages, client caching and passing parameters

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am building a sizable, mobile application that is currently built on top of jQuery Mobile and KnockoutJS. My first approach made heavy use of a Single Page Application design along with loading all dynamic content and data via Knockout and ajax calls. This has worked OK but maintenance and development has become very complicated as jQuery Mobile loads more and more into the DOM.

I wonder about moving to more traditional, individual HTML pages that are completely static while still loading data via Knockout and ajax. This will allow browsers to cache the biggest parts of the app: the HTML pages.

Question:

How can I best pass parameters around from page to page without creating unique URLs that inhibit client-side browser caching? **I want browsers to aggressively cache pages.**

I realize that I can implement all kinds of server side caching but that is not my goal here. `/Display/3` and `/Display/5` are the same page. Will the browser cache these as one?

I wonder about passing parameters after the hash mark? `/Display#3` and `/Display#5`? How about passing parameters via JavaScript in the global namespace?

Hoping for a standard approach here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok sorry for misunderstanding, but I think your approach goes the wrong way. You cannot use GET paramters that way, also JQueryMobile is a little bit confusing in url handling for AJAX.

Normally, if using AJAX to refresh content, you do not need to reload the page. So you need no caching, because the page is already there and only some content is reloaded via AJAX. But JQM's single page approach is not usable for dynamic created content that way. You can only dynamically create a page with all content in it, and JQM shows content by switching visibility. Then the # could be used to switch between the pages (the # does not force an reload, as used for on side navigation).

You can write your own loading function calling in buttons and links (instead of using URL GET paramters). By using JQuery's $.ajax method with dataType "html" (instead of json, default) you can do a content refresh in its success handler.

Answer (score 0):

You could try html5 sessionStorage/localStorage. If html5 is an issue, than plain old cookies.
Just to clarify, if there are several HTML pages, each page must have its own URL.

Comment: I have `page.html` but need to pass a parameter around that ultimately hit my JavaScript. `page.html?id=1` and `page.html?id=3` are all the same page and I want the browser to just cache `page.html`. I don't want the addition of the parameter to create 2 unique pages.